# How to reuse TopAppBar and access its properties

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How can the properties of a top app bar be accessed and reused several times? Are there any limitations towards this approach? I want to be able to change the text in a top app bar when necessary.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val topBarTitle: String = "?"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AirlinesTheme {
                setContent {
                    Scaffold(
                        topBar = { TopBar() },
                        content = {}
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun TopBar() {
        SmallTopAppBar(title = { Text(text = topBarTitle) })
    }
}
```

Comment: you should use Compose mutable state, e.g. `mutableStateOf`, for all properties, that should trigger recomposition on update. no other limitations

Answer (score 0):

Usually the important data is stored inside a ViewModel

```
class MyVM : ViewModel(){
 var topBarProperty by mutableStateOf("Initial")
}
```

Then initialize the VM like this

`val vm by viewModels<MyVM>()`

Now, use the property in your top-bar

```
Scaffold(
                        topBar = { Text(text = vm.topBarProperty) },
                        content = {}
                    )
```

Now, you could do something like `vm.topBarProperty = "Updated"`, from anywhere in your activity, and it will update the value on the topBar. This is because we are using a `MutableState<T>` type variable which will trigger recompositions on the Composables reading it, when modified.

Comment: Explaining stuff to you is super-easy, barely an inconvenience.